# Can't copy from from an S3 bucket in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Added an update (an EDIT) at the bottom

## Info

I have two AWS accounts. One with an S3 bucket and a second one that needs access to it.

On the account with the S3 bucket, the bucket policy looks like this:

```
 {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3ToSecAcc",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Second-AWS-ACC-ID:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
            ]
},
```

In the second account, that tries to get the file from S3, I've attached the following IAM Policy (There are other policies too but this should give it access):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3-object-lambda:Get*",
                "s3-object-lambda:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Problem

Despite everything, when I run the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET-NAME/path/to/file/copied/from/URI.txt .
```

I get:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Did I do something wrong? What did I miss? All my web the web results suggested making sure in the bucket policy I have `/*` and that the IAM policy allows S3 access but it's already there.

---

EDIT: `aws s3 ls` works on the file! It means it just relates to permissions somehow. It works from another AWS that may have uploaded the file. Just need to figure out how to open it up.

Comment: I am assuming the account ID that you have in the bucket policy is that of the second account, right?

Comment: @Paolo Yes, it is. My bad, sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: When you run the `aws s3 cp` command, are you running that from a terminal in which credentials for the second account are configured? If you run `aws sts get-caller-identity`, do you see the second account ID?

Comment: Do these 2nd account credentials work to download an object from an S3 bucket that's actually in the same (2nd) account?

Comment: @Paolo Thanks for the response, running the sts command indeed showed the same account number as I put in the account with the S3. I'm running the `aws s3 cp` command from an EC2 instance in the second account (the one trying to pull from s3)

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the response, I just tested it, it works. It even works with a third AWS account with an S3 bucket with the same policy as the first one!

Comment: Is the first account part of an AWS organization?

Comment: @Paolo I'm not sure, never heard of AWS organizations until now.

Comment: @Paolo @jarmod After hours of debugging I'm getting closer!  `aws s3 ls` works on the file! It means it just relates to permissions somehow. It works from another AWS that may have uploaded the file. Just need to figure out how to open it up. I also created a dummy file and it works on the dummy file! I think that the owner of the file I'm trying to get is problem. Wonder how I can get around that, like what permissions could I set to have it allow getting access to that file as well.

Comment: OK, the problem is likely to be that the object uploaded to account #1 is not owned by account #1. Despite being the owner of the bucket, it's not the owner of the object and hence has no permission to share it. You should consider enabling [Amazon S3 Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) on these buckets to ensure the bucket owner automatically takes ownership of the objects uploaded by other account's IAM principals. Or set the bucket policy to deny any uploads that don't indicate the bucket-owner-full-control ACL.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the response! If I disable ACLs, as AWS recommends, would the other accounts still have access to the files in the bucket, given that the bucket policy dictates they should?

Comment: It depends on how your clients upload files. If they indicate an explicit ACL and you've disabled ACLs then their uploads will fail afaik. Recommend that you read the relevant docs and try things out first.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws s3 cp` command does lots of weird stuff, including (it seems) calling `head-object`.

Try calling the pure S3 API instead:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket BUCKET-NAME --key path/to/file/copied/from/URI.txt .
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm getting the following:
```An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied```